# Component renders before NgOnInit finishes?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngoninit

I've got a component which performs some calls to a service which calls an api. The component renders before these calls are finished, resulting in an empty page.

This is the code from the component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service';
import {AssignmentService} from '../services/assignment.service';
import {Assignment} from '../models/Assignment';
import {Request} from '../models/Request';
import {MeService} from '../services/me.service';
import * as MicrosoftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {NavbarService} from '../services/navbar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-newrequest',
  templateUrl: './newrequest.component.html',
  providers: [AssignmentService]
})
export class NewrequestComponent implements OnInit {
  me: MicrosoftGraph.User;
  assignments: Assignment[];
  requests: Request[] = [];
  ready = false;

  constructor(private meService: MeService,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private assignmentService: AssignmentService,
              private router: Router,
              public nav: NavbarService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nav.show();
    this.nav.element = 'newrequests';
    if (localStorage.getItem('loggedin') === 'yes') {
      this.meService.getMe().subscribe(data => {
          this.me = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => this.assignmentService.getAssignments().subscribe(data => {
            this.assignments = data;
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          },
          () => {
            this.setRequests();
          }));
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  onLogin() {
    this.authService.login();
  }

  private setRequests() {
    this.assignments.forEach(item => {
      if (this.me.mail.toLowerCase() === item.lecturer.toLowerCase()) {
        this.parseRequests(item.request, item.name);
      }
    });

    this.ready = true;
  }

  private parseRequests(toSplit, name) {
    const split = toSplit.split(',');

    split.forEach(item => {
      this.requests.push(new Request(item, name));
    });
  }
}
```

This is the code from the page:

```
<app-navbar-component></app-navbar-component>
<div *ngIf="ready">
  <div *ngFor="let request of requests">
    <p class="lead">{{request.user}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the function in my service:

```
getAssignments() {
    return this.http.get(this.BASE_API_URL + '/assignments').catch(this.onError);
  }
```

I get no errors. The requests are loaded (checked via console.log). The only problem is that the page renders before the data has finished loading.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah that's correct. The HTTP request is asynchronous so it doesn't wait until it's finished.

Comment: How do I circumvent this? I thought the *ngIf would work...

Comment: Circumvent what? Does the data render when the requests finally complete?

Comment: If you do not want page rendering before data is received, you may use router resolve guard.

Comment: The component doesn't render when the requests are complete.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using resolve?

create a resolver name it assignments-details.resolver.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {MeService} from '../services/me.service';

@Injectable()
export class AssignmentsDetailsResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(api: MeService){}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
   return this.api.getAssignments();
  }

}
```

Then on your route config do it like this

```
{
  path: 'your_path',
  component: NewrequestComponent,
  resolve: { AssignmentsDetails: AssignmentsDetailsResolver }
}
```

Then on your NewrequestComponent make sure you import ActivatedRoute

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
```

and in your contructor call it like this

```
 constructor(private meService: MeService,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private assignmentService: AssignmentService,
              private router: Router,
              public nav: NavbarService,
              private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

   this.activateRoute.data.subscribe((response) => {
       //to get the response
       console.log(response.AssignmentsDetails);
     });
  }
```

And also make sure you register 'AssignmentsDetailsResolver' in the provider property of your module.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The resolve method here is the exact answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Since the service call is asynchronous, the data does not arrive immediately when the subscribe is called.

But in your code, you are not setting  ready variable to be true once the data is arrived. So you don't see any data on page. Set it to true once you get the data

```
this.me = data;
this.ready =true;
```

or handle through the safe navigation operator.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think you oversaw the ready part. I set ready on true in the setRequests() function.

Comment: Yes. I've noticed that when I set ready on true on the place you mentioned, it becomes true in the component.

However, this is too soon. The data that it uses has not yet been loaded by that time. I need the assignments data.

Comment: call the setrequests inside subscribe

Comment: Doesn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: am sure your method parseRequest has the issue then. just check if your array has data

Comment: I checked that method extensively. The array has the data... Ready just doesn't become true in the component.